# What do the lines of symbols mean, when creating a Diffie Hellmann parameter file?

Tags: openssl

Just curious: What does this output mean, while creating Diffie Hellmann parameters for encryption in the shell?

`..................................+..................+...................................................+.............+..........................................................................................................................+...........................................................+.....................`

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/what-do-the-dots-and-pluses-mean-when-openssl-generates-keys ?

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, [the answer from Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42055/54387):

> When computing DHPARAM you will get these as the output while
>   computing [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) parameters:
>
> ```
> . : A potential prime number was generated.
> + : Number is being tested for primality.
> * : A prime number was found.
> ```
>
> References:
>
> - [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_external_openssl/blob/master/apps/dhparam.c) (at the bottom)
> - [man pages for the functions](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dhparam.html)

Comment: Just another question: My Banana Pi (OS: Bananian) is currently creating a 4096 bit Diffie Hellman file. It is only showing `.` and `+` and already running for like 2 hours. How long can I expect it to take?

Comment: @adrifromhh sorry, I have no idea. But you might want to create the file elsewhere on a more powerful system and move it to your Pi.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll do that now.

Comment: @adrifromhh when generating a key the system relies on entropy for generating random numbers, and that's "created" by the system doing things (anything).  that's why programs like gpg or ssh-keygen often tell you to do things like move the mouse or have other processes perform disk or network activity.  your Banana Pi probably isn't doing enough to generate enough random numbers for the keygen.  You can either make it do more stuff, or (as muru said) generate the key on a faster, busier system.